# Linearly Independent Vectors of a Set

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

In the question below I have to prove that the span of a set of length $k$ is in the space $R^n$. The question is stated as:

Let $(p^1, . . . , p^k) ⊂ R^n$, where $k ≥ n$.

Does $span[(p^1, . . . , p^k)] = R^n$? (i.e.  does the set $(p^1, . . . , p^k)$ contains $n$ linearly independent vectors?)

I need to show how I can solve this decision problem by solving at most $n$ linear programming problems.

I can also make use of the following result for this:

> Let ${q^1 , . . . , q^n} ⊂ R^n$ be a basis for $R^n$. Then $span[(p^1
> > , . . . , p^k)]=R^n$ if and only if $q^j∈span[(p^1 , . . . , pk)]$ for
> each $j = 1, . . . ,n.$

My thinking for this question is to show that the set $(p^1, . . . , p^k)$ has full row rank (where the number of rows is $n$), which in turn means that the span of $(p^1, . . . , p^k)$ is equal to $R^n$ and the set contains $n$ linearly independent vectors.

Is there any way to prove this?

Comment: The answer is a definite NO. Take $p^{i}=ip$ (if you are not happy with $p^{i}=0$ for all $i$)

Comment: Please do not delete a question after receiving an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person who has taken the time to answer your question, and disrespectful to future readers who might be interested in your  question and its answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check for $i=1,\ldots, n$, whether $$e_i=\sum p^ix_i$$ has a solution. This is a feasibility problem.

If the answers to all of them is yes, then it contains $n$ linearly independent vector.

Comment: what would the variable $x_i$ represent in this instance?

Comment: The decision variables that you want to solve for. The coefficients that would prove that $e_i$ is within the span if it is so.